What group composition is this process involving representing the groups using directed graphs equivalent to?
Here's a process that I discovered for myself:

For two directed graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with the same vertex set $V$ and edge sets $E_1$ and $E_2$, respectively, define $G_1 \circ G_2$ to be a new graph defined as $(V, E)$ where for any $v_1, v_2 \in V, $ the edge $(v_1, v_2)$ is in $E$ if and only if there exists a $v_n \in V$ such that $(v_1, v_n) \in E_1$ and $(v_n, v_2) \in E_2$. Essentially, this treats the two graphs as mappings of points and composes those mappings into a new mapping represented by a new graph.


In addition, define the graph composition operation $*$ such that $(V_1, E_1) * (V_2, E_2) = (V_1 \times V_2, E)$ where $((v_{1a}, v_{2a}), (v_{1b}, v_{2b})) \in E$ if and only if $(v_{1a}, v_{1b}) \in E_1$ and $(v_{2a}, v_{2b}) \in E_2$.


Now, we can represent any group in terms of a underlying set of directed graphs and a group operation $\circ$ (as previously defined). The vertex set for each directed graph is identical and has the same order as the group itself, and each graph can be treated as a mapping of the elements of the group under a specific element. For example, for $C_3$, each graph would have three vertices. The first graph, representing $e$, would have an edge from each point to itself; the second graph, representing $r$, would form a clockwise triangle of sorts; and the third graph, representing $r^2$, would form a counterclockwise triangle (isomorphic to the graph representing $r$).


Finally, define the group extension $A \cdot B$, where the underlying set is the cartesian product of the underlying sets of $A$ and $B$, except replace ordered pairs of graphs with the composition of the two graphs on $*$. The group operation is $\circ$.

That probably is really confusing and worded weirdly but I can't really find a better way to explain it. I know that, through this process, $C_2 \cdot C_3 \cong D_6$, but actually performing the process takes a lot of time. I'm wondering, is there any known group composition operation that performs the same process in a simpler way?
